# Django--Performance hit in using Template Tags vs. Context variables

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm a bit naive as far as Django template processing goes. As far as I understand, template tags are just functions.

So, is there any difference in performance in filtering query sets in template tags

```
   ie. user.profile_set.all.0.followers
```

versus filtering queries in the same manner via my View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template must be parsed, and at each `.` it must [guess which type of access](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) the next identifier should be. Over the long run, avoiding all this can speed the project up a very tiny bit.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Your answer makes complete sense. Good to know I was never screwing it up TOO badly

Answer (score 2):

In and of itself there should be no discernible difference since most of the cost of doing this is in the DB access. However, if the template that contains the template tag that does the DB interaction is being included, possibly more than once on a page, then there could be a very noticeable difference.

Comment: Great point, Peter.  I'm probably not strict enough with my template tag calling