# templatetags vs context in django

Tags: django

after working with django, I see that there seems to be 2 ways of passing data to the html page. Like if I had a model called Products, I can either do

`views.py`

```
context = {
        'products' : Products.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'products/product_page.html', context)
```

`product_page.html`

```
{% for post in posts %}
    //do stuff with {{post}}
{% endfor %}
```

or I can do

`product_tags.py`

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_Products():
    return Products.objects.all()
```

`product_page.html`

```
{% load product_tags %}
{% get_Products as elections %}
    //do stuff with {{elections}}
```

Is one way better than another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of:

[stack Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348575/django-performance-hit-in-using-template-tags-vs-context-variables)

In your example, if you only use it once, I guess its the same performance.

But if for some case you have to "get_Products" twice its a waste of a DB access.

Context for me its the common way. Only write template tags when I need to get something very specific like a query with 3 different models on that are on a for loop.

look at my example:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_skipper_in_training_finish_datetime(training, user):
   skipper = training.get_skipper_in_training(user)
   if skipper:
       return skipper.finish_datetime
```

I have 3 different models in the activity query, and only one has the "finish_datetime"

Utils its a view with all my template tags for this app

```
{% load utils %}

{% regroup activities by start_date|date:'d-m-Y' as activities_by_date %}
    {% for start_date in activities_by_date %}

       {% for activity in start_date.list %}
          ...

          {% if "Training" in activity.model_name %}
             <script>
                 {% get_skipper_in_training_finish_datetime activity user as skipper_finish %}
                 document.write($.format.toBrowserTimeZone("{{ skipper_finish |date:'c' }}", "HH:mm:ss"))
             </script>
          {% elif activity.end_date %}
              <script>document.write($.format.toBrowserTimeZone("{{ activity.end_date|date:'c' }}", "dd-MM-yyyy"))</script>
          {% else %}
             -
          {% endif %}

        ...

       {% endfor %}

       ...

    {% endfor %}
```

Django Docs does not refer to performance when talking about template tags

[Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/)

But as you can see its a matter of logic and complex model usage.

Hope I could help